# Error in using Net::Lite::FTP

Tags: perl, ssl, ftps, tie

I am using the Perl library [`Net::Lite::FTP`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Lite::FTP) for FTP TLS protocol. I am getting the error

```
Damn! undefined response
```

while connecting to a remote. I think the problem is with [`Net::SSLeay::Handle`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSLeay::Handle).

If I comment the line 151, 271, 310, 373 in the `Net/Lite/FTP.pm` library file it is working fine (able to connect remote server and transmit files). But we should not edit the library file, so advise me if there are any other solutions available.

Comment: The first and third of those lines are comments in the latest version (0.61) of the module. You should at least update your installation before asking questions about it

Comment: There is a lot more to that error message. Please would you quote it completely?

Comment: Borodin, Thanks for your response. We are migrating the code which is running in one platform to a newer one. As per the requirement the library version should be same (i.e 0.54). Please find the full error msg "Damn! undefined response (err:) {H: IP address P:21} Damn! undefined response (err:) {H: IP address P:21} Damn! undefined response (err:) {H: IP address P:21} use of uninitialized value $temp in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/local/share/perl15/Net/Lite/FTP.pm line 423...problem sending PASV request at /usr/local/share/perl15/Net/Lite/FTP.pm line 423".

Comment: I have tried the latest version 0.61 also.. which is throwing the error "Prototype mismatch: sub Net::Lite::FTP::IP_TOS none vs() at /usr/local/share/perl15/Exporter.pm line 66 at /usr/local/share/perl15/Net/Lite/FTP.pm line 145 setsocket Invalid argument at /usr/local/share/perl15/Net/Lite/FTP.pm line 147.

Answer (score 0):

You can instead try **Net::FTPSSL** if you need FTP client over a SSL or TLS connection. It will use TLS by default.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question

Comment: Hi @Borodin he has mentioned "any other solution" in his question, so I have provided this.

Comment: Amareesh, thanks for the reply...I am supposed to use the Library Net::Lite::FTP only.

Comment: The issue was with the server side. changed vsdfd.conf file to support TLS protocol and it worked..